# Accessing images using URL from a server with restrictions in React

Tags: python, reactjs, django

I'm working on a web application using React for the front end and Django for the backend, where I need to display images from a server that has access restrictions in place. These restrictions prevent direct access to the images via a URL(tho I still can access it if I just paste the link into a browser), which is causing issues when trying to display them on my website.

Here is an example of the image URL: 'https://mangatx.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Level-1-Player-Manga-Online-193x278.jpg'

I've tried using the standard `<img>` HTML tag to display these images, but I'm encountering a 403 error, indicating that I don't have permission to access the images directly.

I have also used a Django templating engine to try to display an image, and it worked somehow, but when I switched to react, it didn't work.

Is there a recommended approach or workaround for displaying these images in my web application, considering the server restrictions? I do not want to download the images before displaying them as it will go against the purpose of the application. I also don't want to use a proxy server, as my application has a lot of images and it will be too inefficient.

Any ideas would be appreciated!!

P.S. Here is my code for displaying an image, just in case:

```
 <div className="text-center">
                          <img
                            src={manga.preview_img}
                            className="img-fluid rounded mx-auto d-block"
                            alt={`${manga.title} Preview`}
                          />
                        </div>
```

Comment: Can you show what is the error in the Network tab (Broswer dev tools) of that specific request when you try via react?